# How to catch and handle Server 500 error in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, web

Hi guys I have been struggling finding a way to catch and handle my 500 errors. I am trying to write data to a MySql database. The method in my controller receives all the data with no problem The following is the code in the method

```
public function new_league(Request $request)
    {

        $venueIDAR = \App\Venue::where('name',$request->venue_name)->get();
        $venueID = \App\Venue::find($venueIDAR[0]->id);
        $venueID = $venueID->id;
        

        $venueName = ($request->venue_name);
        $venueName = str_replace(' ', '_', $venueName);
        $lDate = ($request->date);
        $dateDay = date('D', strtotime($lDate));
        $lDate = str_replace('-', '_', $lDate);
        
        $leagueName = $venueName . '_' . $dateDay . '_' . $lDate;
        $lDate = str_replace('_', '-', $lDate);

        $new_league = \App\Leagues::create([
            'LeagueName' => $leagueName,
            'venueId' => $venueID,
            'date' => $request->date . ":00",
        ]);

        return $new_league;
        //$TheLeague->save();
        
        return redirect()->back();
    }
```

Everything works up until the following code

```
$new_league = \App\Leagues::create([
            'LeagueName' => $leagueName,
            'venueId' => $venueID,
            'date' => $request->date,
        ]);
```

Then I receive a 500 error, I have tried checking the log file but its not logging this problem. How do I catch this exception to get a more detailed response than just 500. This will greatly help me with future problems as well

I have tried a different way of inserting into into the database by means of the following code separately

```
DB::insert('insert into paperclipsa.leagues (LeagueName, venueId, date) values (?, ?, ?)', [$leagueName, $venueID, $request->date . " 00:00:00"]);

DB::insert('insert into paperclipsa.leagues (LeagueName, venueId, date) values (?, ?, ?)', ["Test", 11, '2021-08-24 00:00:00']);
```

But neither works the following statement when used directly in MySql does work

```
INSERT INTO paperclipsa.leagues (LeagueName, venueId, date)
VALUES ("Test", 11, '2021-08-24 00:00:00');
```

So I'm still not sure why it is giving the error.
I am however able to retrieve existing data in the database with the following so I don't think it is a connection issue

```
$exist = \App\League::where('venueId', $venueID) -> get();
```

Thank you

Comment: There are many things that could be wrong, and PHP will always log the actual error when you see a 500 Server Error message. Find the right log file. The actual error could be something as simple as the trailing comma after `'date' => $request->date,`, if you're using PHP7.1 or below.

Comment: Hi thank you for the response, how would I go about finding the correct log file, I only have the one in **storage/logs/laravel.log** and the last error logged is from **[2021-08-12 12:17:52]** but nothing from today or last week when I also ran into problems.

Comment: @armand is it a laravel styled error page? if not, you can look in your server error log. You can also use a PHP try/catch to output or log the error. Just a guess... The model is called `Leagues`? normally the model would be called `League` in Laravel

Comment: @GertB. Hi gert I am very new to laravel I picked this project up from a friend that had someone else previously work on it, so Im learning as I go along what would a laravel style error page look like? It is mostly a blank page that just says ** 500 Whoops, something went wrong on our servers. ** And where can I find the server error logs? Is the try catch available in the laravel documentation?

Comment: @GertB. This is how I created the table in MySql by using migrations ``` Schema::create('leagues', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('LeagueName');
            $table->integer('venueId');
            $table->datetime('date');
            $table->timestamps();
        }); ``` If this help I also changed the data sent to date time as follow but still no luck ** 'date' => $request->date . " 00:00:00" **

Comment: @armand a table leagues will typically have a model `League` unless you change the table name in the model. The error log file can be in different locations. It's strange to me that you don't get a laravel error, that you can find in laravel.log. Does your application work if you comment out that line?

Comment: I just rolled back the migration and started from scratch the model is now named "League" and when the migration is run It created the table "Leagues" in MySql, I tried running it again as well as commenting out that line but still a 500 error, I also find it strange because I am using code that does work as a template and just changed to create my changes but it doesn't seem to help so it the entire create statement. I do believe the laravel.log file has been used from the start because it is a 120gb file dating back to 2018

Comment: @GertB. When I insert data manually in my sql and then request it as follow ``` $exist = \App\League::where('venueId', $venueID) -> get(); ``` I get feedback so I dont think its and access problem, could it have something to do with the datatypes but I doubt this because I havent seen datatypes used with any of the other insert methods in the website

Answer (score 0):

first you should do this. because it is fetching all records related to the requested venue name. but you want only one. second using $venueIDAR[0]->id, you should use $venueIDAR->id.

```
$venueIDAR=\App\Venue::where('name',$request->venue_name)->first();
 $venueID = \App\Venue::find($venueIDAR->id);
```

I hope. i kept my point properly

Comment: Hi I changed it the code to yours and the VenueId I receive, I do this by returning using return $venueId is the same as the one I got. Thus the error still persist but thank you for the contribution.

Comment: yes you get the id as you were getting the same before but suppose you have multiname venue names then it will return an array as your code. but by my code you will get only name which you want to fetch but same you will get the record which is the first only may be your record is 3rd number but again you will get the record at first record only . so always try to fetch the record by id only that can never be repeated. instead of fetching by the string

Comment: Thank you for the tip will keep it in mind in the future when fetching data